# Firebase V9 does not give error in catch when offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I want to set state in catch even if user offline but firebase V9 setDoc does not give anything in catch when user offline

For Example: in Authentication, if the user offline firebase gives (network error) in catch but in firestore "add document" no message from catch.

**Example Code:**

```js
try {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "new-city-2"), data) 
    console.log("Document Written Successfully");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(`error found! ${err}`); 
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code and instead use StackOverflow's code formatting tools (click the help icon in the corner of the editor or view the [full guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so code, questions and answers may be searched.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design thanks to [Firestore's Offline Behaviour](https://youtu.be/oDvdAFP6OhQ?t=673) (queued up to the right spot, but I do recommend watching in full).

The promise will resolve once the server has acknowledged the request. If the server is currently unavailable, that request is cached within the SDK and attempted as soon as a connection is restored. During this window, the Promise will be kept in its pending state because that's the state its actually in - pending. While the promise may not resolve, all your local realtime listeners and such will still fire off and your app will function as normal - just offline.

Dealing with this behaviour is an exercise for the developer. One way to approach this would be to use `Promise.race()` to implement your own offline-handling logic.

As a quick & dirty example, here's a `setDocWithTimeout` implementation:

```js
const setDocWithTimeout = (ref, data, options) => {
  const timeoutMS = options && options.timeout || 10000;
  const setDocPromise = setDoc(ref, data);

  return Promise.race([
    setDocPromise.then(() => ({ timeout: false })),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, timeoutMS, { timeout: true, promise: setDocPromise }));
  ]);
}
```

which you can apply using:

```js
try {
  const result = await setDocWithTimeout(doc(db, "cities", "new-city-2"), data);
  if (result.timeout) {
    // offline? (could be poor connection too)
    console.log("Document added to Firestore queue");
    // dismiss any blocking UIs/loading bubbles
    // tell user will be written to server later
    await result.promise; // wait for write to complete as before
  }

  // online! (or back online)
  console.log("Document written successfully!");
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`error found! ${err}`);
}
```

Alternatively where an error is thrown:

```js
const setDocWithTimeoutError = (ref, data, options) => {
  const timeoutMS = options && options.timeout || 10000;
  const setDocPromise = setDoc(ref, data);

  return Promise.race([
    setDocPromise,
    new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, timeoutMS, new Error("timeout"));
  ]);
}
```

which you can apply using:

```js
try {
  await setDocWithTimeoutError(doc(db, "cities", "new-city-2"), data);
  console.log("Document written successfully!");
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`error found! ${err}`);
}
```

Comment: Great answer Sam!  A few points: 1) Firestore doesn't see being offline as an error condition, which is why it doesn't signal it as such. Instead it handles the offline behavior gracefully and transparently for most cases. 2) In most cases you can assume that the write will eventually make it to the server once the call to `setDoc` has returned. So that's where you often will want to reenable UI elements. 3) To show that a write this is pending locally for synchronization to the server, use the `metadata.hasPendingWrites` of the snapshot. That will also update once the write is committed.

Answer (score 0):

works on web v9, see
[docs from v8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase#onlog).

```js
import { onLog } from 'firebase/app';

onLog((e) => {
  const { level, message } = e;
    if (level === 'warn') {
      console.log('connection interruption after intial load was success:', message);
    }
    if (level === 'error') {
      console.log('no connection on inital load:', message);
    }
});
```